# How to model several tournaments / brackets types into a SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I want to model a database to store data of several types of tournaments (whith different types of modes: single rounds, double rounds, league, league + playoffs, losers, ...).

Maybe, this project would be a kind of Challonge: www.challonge.com

My question is: How to create a model in sql-relationship database to store all this types of tournaments?

I can't imagine how to do this work. There is a lot of different tables but all tables is related to one attribute: tournamentType...

Can I store a tournamentType field and use this field to select the appropiate table on query?

Thanks you

Comment: So, each tournament type has different data requirements, thus needing a different table with unique structure?

Comment: @Turophile Yes, it's

Comment: How about you describe some of the tournaments you want to model?  That would be a good starting point to understanding what you're after.
Using a different table for each type would make sense until commonalities arise.

Comment: It depends on how similair the different types of tournaments are, really. I would do it with your one attribute, "tournamentType", but have one generic table for a "Game". This way, you have one list of all the games that are played, but you can still differentiate between the different types of tournaments.

Comment: hi @Mou, did you ever a find a suitable schema/solution for this? I am facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can understand why you're struggling with modeling this. One of the key reasons why this is difficult is because of the [object relational impendance-mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). While I am a huge fan of SQL and it is an incredibly powerful way of being able to organize data, one of its downfalls - and why NoSQL exists - is because SQL is different from Object Oriented Programming. When you describe leagues, with different matches, it's pretty easy to picture this in object form: A `Match` object is extended by `League_Match`, `Round_Match`, `Knockout_Match`, etc. Each of these `Match` objects contains two `Team` objects. `Team` can be extended to `Winner` and `Loser`...

But this is not how SQL databases work.

So let's translate this into relationships:

> I want to model a database to store data of several types of tournaments (whith different types of modes: single rounds, double rounds, league, league + playoffs, losers, ...).

- Tournaments and "modes" are a one to many (1:n) relationship.
- Each tournament has many teams, and each team can be part of many tournaments (n:n).
- Each team has many matches, and each match has two teams (n:n).
- Each tournament has multiple matches but each match only belongs to one tournament (1:n).

The missing piece here that is hard to define as a universal relationship?
- In rounds, each future match has two teams.
- In knockout matches, each future match has an exponential but shrinking number of choices depending on the number of initial teams.

You could define this in the database layer or you could define this in your application layer. If your goal is to keep referential integrity in mind (which is one of the key reasons I use SQL databases) then you'll want to keep it in the database.

Another way of looking at this: I find that it is easiest for me to design a database when I think about the end result by thinking of it as JSON (or an array, if you prefer) that I can interact with.

Let's look at some sample objects:

Tournament:

```
[
    {
        name: "team A",
        schedule: [
            {
                date: "11/1/15",
                vs: "team B",
                score1: 2,
                score2: 4
             },
             {
                date: "11/15/15",
                vs: "team C",
             }
        ]
    }
],
[
   //more teams
]
```

As I see it, this works well for everything except for knockout, where you don't actually know which team is going to play which other team until an elimination takes place. This confirms my feeling that we're going to create descendants of a `Tournament` class to handle specific types of tournaments.

Therefore I'd recommend three tables with the following columns:

```
Tournament
- id (int, PK)
- tournament_name
- tournament_type

Team
- id (int, PK)
- team_name (varchar, not null)
# Any other team columns you want.

Match
- id (int, PK, autoincrement)
- date (int)
- team_a_score (int, null)
- team_b_score (int, null)
- status (either future, past, or live)
- tournament_id (int, Foreign Key)

Match_Round
- match_id (int, not null, foreign key to match.id)
- team_a_id (int, not null, foreign key to team.id)
- team_b_id (int, not null, foreign key to team.id)

Match_Knockout
- match_id (int, not null, foreign key to match.id)
- winner__a_of (match_id, not null, foreign key to match.id)
- winner_b_of (match_id, not null, foreign key to match.id)
```

You have utilized sub-tables in this model. The benefit to this is that knockout matches and round/league matches are very different and you are treating them differently. The downside is that you're adding additional complexity which you're going to have to handle. It may be a bit annoying, but in my experience trying to avoid it only adds more headaches and makes it far less scalable.

Now I'll go back to referential integrity. The challenge with this setup is that theoretically you could have values in both `Match_Round` and `Match_Knockout` when they only belong in one. To prevent this, I'd utilize `TRIGGER`s. Basically, stick a trigger on both the `Match_Round` and `Match_Knockout` tables, which prevents an `INSERT` if the `tournament_type` is not acceptable.

Although this is a bit of a hassle to set up, it does have the happy benefit of being easy to translate into objects while still maintaining referential integrity.

Answer (score 3):

You could create tables to hold tournament types, league types, playoff types, and have a schedule table, showing an even name along with its tournament type, and then use that relationship to retrieve information about that tournament. Note, this is not MySQL, this is more generic SQL language:

```
CREATE TABLE tournTypes (
ID int autoincrement primary key,
leagueId int constraint foreign key references leagueTypes.ID,
playoffId int constraint foreign key references playoffTypes.ID
--...other attributes would necessitate more tables
)

CREATE TABLE leagueTypes(
ID int autoincrement primary key,
noOfTeams int,
noOfDivisions int,
interDivPlay bit -- e.g. a flag indicating if teams in different divisions would play
)

CREATE TABLE playoffTypes(
ID int autoincrement primary key,
noOfTeams int,
isDoubleElim bit -- e.g. flag if it is double elimination
)

CREATE TABLE Schedule(
ID int autoincrement primary key,
Name text,
startDate datetime,
endDate datetime,
tournId int constraint foreign key references tournTypes.ID
)
```

Populating the tables...

```
INSERT INTO tournTypes VALUES
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,3),
(3,1)

INSERT INTO leagueTypes VALUES
(16,2,0), -- 16 teams, 2 divisions, teams only play within own division
(8,1,0),
(28,4,1)

INSERT INTO playoffTypes VALUES
(8,0), -- 8 teams, single elimination
(4,0),
(8,1)

INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES
('Champions league','2015-12-10','2016-02-10',1),
('Rec league','2015-11-30','2016-03-04-,2)
```

Getting info on a tournament...

```
SELECT Name
,startDate
,endDate
,l.noOfTeams as LeagueSize
,p.noOfTeams as PlayoffTeams
,case p.doubleElim when 0 then 'Single' when 1 then 'Double' end as Elimination
FROM Schedule s
INNER JOIN tournTypes t
ON s.tournId = t.ID
INNER JOIN leagueTypes l
ON t.leagueId = l.ID
INNER JOIN playoffTypes p
ON t.playoffId = p.ID
```

Comment: That does not allow custom types of scoring for each league.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to make data models far more complex than they need to be.  A lot of what you describe is business logic that can't actually be answered by a perfect data model.  Most of the tournament logic should be captured outside the data model in a programming language, such as mysql functions, Java, Python, C# etc.  Really your data model should be all "static" data you need, and none of the moving parts.  I would suggest the data model to be:

### METADATA TABLES

League_Type:

- Id
- Description
- Playoff_Rounds
- Resolve_Losing_Teams
- Max_Number_of_Teams
- Min_Number_of_Teams
- Number_Of_Games_In_Season
- any other "settings" you want...

Game_Type:

- Id
- League_Type_Id (fk to League_Type)
- Game_Type_Name (e.g. regular season, playoff, championship)

### DATA TABLES

League:

- Id
- League_Type_Id (fk to League_Type)
- League_Name

Team:

- Id
- League_Id (fk to League_Type)
- Team_Name

Game:

- Id
- League_Id (fk to League_Type)
- Game_Type_Id (fk to Game_Type)
- Home_Team_Id (fk to Team)
- Visiting_Team_Id (fk to Team)
- Week_of_season
- Home_Team_Score
- Visiting_Team_Score
- Winning_Team (Home or Visitor)

---

From a data model perspective that should really be all you need.  The procedural code should handle things like:

- Creating games based on a randomized schedule
- Updating scores and winning team in the Game table
- Creating playoff games based on when the number of games in the season is up per the league settings table.
- Setting matchups in the playoffs based on how many games each team has one.
- Forcing the number of teams in a league to be between Min_Number_of_Teams and Max_Number_of_Teams prior to the season beginning.
- Etc.

You'll also likely want to create some views based on these tables to create some other meaningful information for end users:

- Wins/Losses for a team (based on the Team table joined to the Game table)
- Current team standings based on the previous wins/losses view for all teams
- Home wins for a team
- Road wins for a team
- Anything else your heart desires!

**Final thoughts**

You do not want to do anything that would repeat data stored in the database.  A great example of this would be creating a separate table for playoff games vs. regular season games.  Most of the columns would be duplicated because almost *all* of the functionality and data stored between the two tables is the same.  To create both tables would break the rules of normalization.  The more compact and simple your data structure can be, the less procedural code you will have to write, and the easier it will be to maintain your database.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a *generalization/specialization* problem to me. I will answer how to do this in a general way, as you didn't give much detail about the entities you acttually need.

Suppose you have an entity `Vehicle` (replacing your tournament) and the specialization `Train` and `Car`. All Vehicles have an attribute `maxSpeed` and Train has `numberOfWagons` and `Car` has `trunkCapacity`.

To model this, you have several options:

**(1) Merge them all into one table**

You can create one table `Vehicle` with columns maxSpeed, numberOfWagons and trunkCapacity. You add another field `vehicleType` to distinguish between Trains and Cars, and you'll probably want an `Id`.

For any concrete Verhicle some of the columns will always be null.

**(2) use separate super/sub tables**

Alternatively you can create a table `Vehicle` with just `Id` and `maxSpeed` and create tables for `Train` and `Car` which just hold the extra attributes, namely numberOfWagons and trunkCapacity (and also an Id).

In this case, creating a new Car will require two inserts, one in the Vehicle Table and one in the Car Table. To select a car you would have to join Vehicle and Car, unless you are only interested in its vehicle attributes.

While this approach is more complicated than (1) it has some benefits

- you will not have that many null columns. A contraint like "the trunkCapacity of a car must not be null" can be easily epressed.
- you can add new Verhicle Types by just adding new tables and without changing any of the existing ones.

**Converting between the two**

- From (2), you can still get a "merged" view (as in (1))  of all your vehicles by creating a view. This view will be a union of several selects, where each select joins one specialization (Train or Car) with Vehicle and adds constant null columns for the attributes it cannot retrieve from the specialization, so all selects in the union return the same number of columns.
- From (1) you can create individual views for Trains and Cars by selecting a particular vehicle type from the Vehicle table and only the columns which are relevant for that vehicle type.

**(3) A mixture of the two**

You can merge the most prominent attributes into one table and exile the more exotic attributes into extra tables.

**A word of caution**

One must be careful not to overdo generalizations. It is often better to just model a Cat as a Cat. In object-oriented programming, generalization ("Superclasses") are treasured. There is saves code duplication, but column duplication is not nearly as bad as code duplication. Remember that you're just modelling data and not behaviour. And also in OO-land generalizations are often overdone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the complexity of this model. Let's see:

[image]

You need:

- Tournaments table (to uniquely define each tournament - league, cup, etc.)
- Tournament types, periods and phases (to define each tournament characteristics)
- Matchups (every single match of every tournament, including home and visitor teams and the final score)

  - Matchup types (linked to the tournament phases)
  - Teams, roster and players (last 2 optional if you intend to add that level of information)

So as an example:

- tournament: Premier Leage
- tournament type: league
- tournament_period: 2015-2016
- tournament_phase: 20th round
- matchup: Chelsea VS Liverpool
- matchup_type: second leg
- score_visitor: 2
- score_local: 0

or

- tournament: Champions league
- tournament type: tournament
- tournament_period: 2015-2016
- tournament_phase: 2nd Round
- matchup_type: first leg
- matchup: Chelsea VS Barcelona
- score_visitor: 5
- score_local: 0

I did this pretty fast so the relationships and columns might not be right, but I guess you have a start point.

Hope it helps!

Regards

Answer (score -2):

Not an elegant solution, but you could do the following:

Create a table that holds key value pairs of attributes for a given tournament. Each tournament would be stored in multiple rows.

```
CREATE TABLE TOURNAMENT {
    TOURNAMENT_TYPE VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    TOURNAMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_VALUE VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
};
```

e.g.

```
TOURNAMENT_TYPE,TOURNAMENT_NAME,ATTRIBUTE_NAME,ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
Volleyball,My volleyball tournament,team_member_1,Josie
Volleyball,My volleyball tournament,team_member_2,Ralph
Volleyball,My volleyball tournament,Rounds Per Game,12
Soccer,My volleyball tournament,team_member_1,Jim
Soccer,My soccer tournament,team_member_2,Emma
Soccer,My soccer tournament,Tournament Duration,20
```

Comment: I hope that exists a better solution

Comment: For unstructed data there is - it's called NoSQL, but since you specifically asked for a SQL database I provided this. The above uses a key value pair in the same spirit as a NoSQL database. If you're willing to define one table per tournament type, you could link each with a foreign key to a primary key for the TOURNAMENT table, but in that case you have to know the types in advance and adding attributes (and supporting code) is non-trivial.